# Getting "java: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist" while building the project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

Hii I have been facing error while building the project in IntelliJ. My laptop is MacBook M1 Pro. My Java version is "11.0.14" and my language level is 11. When I build this in intellij it fails with this error saying "java: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist". But while building in maven on the terminal i.e, on the command line with the same java version and language level it works fine and it builds successfully.

Any help for resolving this error.
Thanks.

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee1nh.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPLZq.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better.

Comment: When you are in IntelliJ, please go to `File -> Project Structure` and add a screenshot of your project settings to your post.

Comment: @Laisender okay

Comment: Looks normal, this problem sometimes occurs when you use the `JRE` instead of `JDK` Version but in your case thats not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When Java version problems occur try checking out 3 things:

1. File -> Project structure -> Project -> Language Version (as I see, in your project everything's ok)
2. File -> Project structure -> Modules -> Language Version (must be 11)[image: like this]
3. File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Target bytecode version (must be 11)[image: like this]

After all try restarting IDE.